# Minimum element estimation of A*A^T

Tags: matrices, inner-product

I want to estimate the minimum element of A*A^T using only the information of A.

For example, maximum element can be estimated using the norm values of all rows without calculating all elements of multiplication.

In similar way, is there any method to estimate the minimum element of A*A^T without conducting the multiplication?

Thank you all.

Comment: "using only the information of $A$" -- no other information is needed to obtain each element of $A^\ast A^{\rm T}$, but you will need that information, so I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: To obtain the minimum element of A∗A^T, one trivial method is to calculate all element of A*A^T (matrix multiplication). However, without conducting A*A^T, I want to predict the minimum element using matrix A.

Comment: In summary, I want to reduce the computational complexity to estimate the minimum value of A*A^T

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "estimate". If you mean "find $C(A)>0$ such that $C(A) \leq \min |(AA^T)_{ij}|$", I don't think there is a smart way to do it.

Comment: I meant I want to predict the value of min{(AA^T)ij} and in my case, (AA^T)ij is positive value.